# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' Issue , flutter.gradle' line: 1070

Tags: android, dart, gradle, flutter-web, flutter-test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: I am trying so many methods but failed. anybody help me, this flutter was built 2 years ago and I am trying to migrate this file v2. now solve all errors but now exceptions have occurred.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.